# Need Alternative to Cells() Command to Reference Strings

Tags: vba, excel

Oddly enough, I am surprised that I cannot find this information online! I am trying to use the following code:

```
If Cells(RowCount, 215).Value = "Edge Roughness" Then
    sb.Append "ER"
End If
```

The cell needs to be an exact match to the text string. For example, some cells are just "Width" while some are "Width Roughness"

Can somebody explain why I cannot use the `Cells(RowCount, 215)` command? Key note: it has to be variable so that I can use the RowCount command.

Comment: Dunno, why can't you? `Cells(1,215)` is the 215th column on the first row ... what happens when you use it?

Comment: Application defined or object defined error. I can post the entire code if necessary.

Comment: Yes as what you have should work

Comment: Are you referring to a cell on another workbook? and what is the value of `RowCount` when you get this error? How does `RowCount` get it's value. Please supply the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use range. It is for the worksheet.

```
Range("A" & RowCount).Value
```

Comment: This does not allow me to use the variable RowCount

Comment: Can I do Range("A"RowCount)?

Comment: Sure it does, the declaration is just a little different. You'd need to convert the column number to a column letter then use Range(columnLetter & RowCount).Value.

You can also do Range("A" & RowCount).Value